# Easy way to port C++ code using std::array to use CUDA thrust?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have existing C++11 code using std::array in the following form:

```
#include <array>
const unsigned int arraySize = 1024;
#define ARRAY_DEF std::array<int, arraySize>

int main()
{
    ARRAY_DEF x;
    x.fill(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Throughout the code, I use the ARRAY_DEF for easy readability, and make it easier to maintain.  No problems there.

Now I'd like to port the code to run in CUDA on the GPU.  Problem, as std::array cannot run on the device.

I think I need to leverage `thrust::device_vector`, but I can't see an easy way to declare a vector of static size in a #define. (I only see doing it after the variable name in the constructor, which defeats the point of using the #define.)

Is there another approach to declaring the vector, with static size, within a #define?

Or is there perhaps another class I can use within CUDA libraries to mimic the std::array to run on the device?

Comment: And no, there is not a functional equivalent to `std::array` in thrust, or a way of doing what you want with static declaration with a vector. The size is a constructor argument and constructors are executed at runtime. That is how the C++ object model works and why `std::array` was invented in the first place. You would need to either write your own implementation with the features you actually need, or use a statically sized C style array

Comment: I agree typedef is better. The same problem would occur either way though.

Comment: Regarding this: `Is there another approach to declaring the vector, with static size, within a #define`  For host code usage, you could do something like this: `#define INTVEC_DEF(x) thrust::device_vector<int> x(arraySize)`.  Using thrust, we don't normally use such definitions directly in device code.  In any event, I suggest reading the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide), for examples of typical/basic usage of thrust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all!  Sadly, none of these answers fit my need.
I took matters into my own hands, and created a class which mimics std::array (mostly), can run in a device/kernel function, and was largely a find/replace to edit.  (Ok, I needed to replace other STL functions, but that's another question.)
https://github.com/MikeBSilverman/CUDAHostDeviceArray (dead link)

Hope it helps someone else.